# Hartl's RoR Chapter 8.2.5 - UsersController sign_in undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm going through Hartl's RoR Tutorial, Chapter 8.2.5 (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_upon_signup) and I couldn't get the "User Pages signup with valid information should create a user" test to past, receiving the following error messages:

```
1) User Pages signup with valid information should create a user
 Failure/Error: expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `sign_in' for #<UsersController:0x007fcdb3b066d8>
```

I was able to find a work-around this by using

```
include SessionsHelper
```

in the users_controller.rb. Did anybody else experience the same things (and this was a implied step in the tutorial) or did I miss a step?

EDIT: As per Sevenseacat's comment, I missed step 8.2.1 where he included it in his ApplicationController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He includes the `SessionsHelper` into his `ApplicationController` in section 8.2.1, here:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-remember_me

And your `UsersController` should extend from `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I misread those instructions and included `SessionsHelper` in `SessionsController` not `ApplicationController` so I still got the previous tests to pass. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already `include SessionsHelper` in your `ApplicationController` as mentioned in section 8.2.1?

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-remember_me